# unable to ssh into raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, ssh

My raspberry pi 2 is connected to my home Wi-Fi. While I'm able to `ssh pi@<ip address>` into raspberry pi at home, I'm ***unable*** to do so from my office in school.

When I connect my raspberry pi 2 to the Wi-Fi in school (the one without password, I seem unable to connect to the Wi-Fi with password), I'm ***unable*** to ssh into raspberry pi either. When I connect my laptop to the schools network I have to authenticate myself with username and password in the web browser.

Why is that? Does that have something to do with the configuration of the Wi-Fi in school?

Comment: Very many institutional networks prevent clients from interfering with each other, either accidentally or deliberately.

Comment: `the one without password` is probably the key ... the device you are using to try to ssh into the pi, is it also connected to `the one without password`?

Comment: Do you use Raspbian? If so, do you have modified its default networking setup, e.g. giving your RasPi a static ip address? What dns name do you use to connect to the RasPi on both sites?

Comment: @JaromandaX, my raspberry pi is connected to the Wi-Fi without password, but my mac, the device I'm using to try to ssh into the pi, is connected to the Wi-Fi with password. Shall I try using the same Wi-Fi?

Comment: @Ingo, yes, I'm using Raspbian. How can I change static ip? And how can I check the dns name?

Comment: Don't use a static ip address. It will increase the problems with connecting to two networks. That was the reason I asked for it. The dns name is the name do you use to connect to the RasPi. e.g. *raspberrypi.local* in `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`. How do you connect to the RasPi with ssh? If you connect to the schools network with a laptop, do you have to authenticate yourself with username/password in a browser?

Comment: @Ingo, here is how I ssh into pi: ssh pi@<ip address> And yes, I do authenticate myself with username and password when connecting my laptop to the network.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the schools network uses a proxy server to connect to it. You can connect to the WiFi hotspot without password but you do not get access to the network. The authentication isn't done on the WiFi hotspot, it is done on the higher level proxy server. It will block any communication if you do not enter username/password to it.

For the RasPi it is a problem. After connecting to the hotspot is has to start a web browser and enter username/password. I don't know if you have a monitor/keyboard attached to the RasPi to use the web browser. I don't believe. So you have to do it automatically by script and that is not an easy task. I have done it using the command line browsing tool `curl` but cannot give generic advises because it depends on extremely what html sides exactly the proxy server expect. Instead of `curl` you can also use `python3` with its browser module, just what you like more.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot connect to your Pi which is at home, from outside the home, is probably that you do not have, or are not using, a globally-routable IP address.

Unless you have a static IP address assigned by your ISP (which you'd probably have to pay for), your best bet will be to set up [DDNS](https://www.lifewire.com/definition-of-dynamic-dns-816294).  You will receive an address, such as `tracy.someservice.net` which will (by the magic of DDNS) resolve to whatever IP address your ISP gives you at any given time.

Comment: Talking about a public ip address doesn't make much sense in this case. The OP do not want to be reachable on the internet all over the world. He only want to connect to the (private?) subnet of the school.

Comment: @Ingo The grammar and punctuation in the question make it a little ambiguous, but I interpreted the first paragraph to mean that, in one case, the Pi was at home and she was at school. That's the problem for which I;m suggesing DDNS.

Comment: @MarkSmith, can you provide more concrete steps on how to do this? How to set up DDNS, and how to use that to connect to raspberry pi from my mac?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Pi2 and the device you are using to connect it in same network? E.g. connected to the same Wi-Fi box? And to answer your question: Yes, it is possible that this Wi-Fi box is blocking your SSH. So it's best to ask local IT admins to get 100% answer.